# Type is not Callable

Tags: compiler-errors, solidity, smartcontracts

```
contract MentalHealthCoin is ERC20, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {

    constructor() ERC20("Mental Health Coin", "MHC") {
      _mint(msg.sender, 500000000(10**uint256(decimals()))); 
    }
```

Hi does anyone know why this is happening.

Thanks

I tried changing the brackets but did not seem to work. I am now thinking if it has something to do with mint function

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add * after 500000000.

```
contract MentalHealthCoin is ERC20, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {

    constructor() ERC20("Mental Health Coin", "MHC") {
      _mint(msg.sender, 500000000*(10**uint256(decimals()))); 
    }
}
```